# Is it possible to use HTML invoice?

Tags: magento

I found it very hard to customize PDF invoice that Magento use. Not only hard to customize, but my client does not like it as well.

Is it possible to disable PDF invoice and use HTML invoice?

I googled it, but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three real options here to get better invoices:

1. Write a better invoice system that
   still uses PDFs. I've done this for
   a client, it takes a long time. Unfortunately, there is no really good way to change the PDFs that Magento generates by default.
2. Replace the controller/action that
   generate the PDFs with ones that
   will simply output HTML.
3. Same as above, but override the
   mass-action dropdown to contain your
   new entries. This is probably the
   easiest, and you can add more
   reports while you're at it. Take a
   look at
   `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`,
   specifically `_prepareMassaction`

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? We would also like to customie the invoice and are hoping for HTML

Answer (score 0):

http://ext4mage.com/html2pdf-magento-extension.html#

grateful, grateful

But I find it a shame that magento does not have thi in core